# Slow response from IIS server for my python flask application

Tags: python, iis

I have created a web application in python using the Flask framework. I have hosted this python application in IIS on windows server2012.

when I called this application with URL `https://localhost/` on the server machine, I am getting a quick response(less than a second). But when I tried to call the same application from another machine inside the corporate network, it is taking more than 2mins time to get the response. I am calling the web application through the IP address of the server machine `i.e XX.XXX.XX.XXX:80.`

could anyone answer why is it taking too much time and how to get rid of this latency time?

I have used below resources to create the web application and opening the inbound port.

python deployment:
https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

Inbound port opening:
https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html

Regards,
Naresh.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved, i have tried with host name instead of IP address. It is so fast.
Regards,
Naresh.